# How to make import/export operations on Oracle Data Integrator 10.1.3 Project?

Tags: oracle

We are studying on Oracle Data Integrator and we want to move our ODI project from one pc to another. Both computers are identical. we managed to export project via OdiExportWork from Designer as in .rar file format. But we could not managed to import it. How can we do that?

Any kind of help is welcome.
Regards.

Comment: Right click on project and export it in XML format

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are able to export as XML file. You may do it as folder by folder or interface by interface or you may export/import whole project.

Just right click on the object you want to export and then select an export location, carry the XML file to the new computer then import it into your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of ODI studio has ability to export/import project, model, related knowledge module etc at one go.

This feature is named as smart export /import. It comes from version 11.1.6.0.